# How to write into this DataFrame?

Tags: python, database, function, dataframe, csv

I'm trying to call open_and_read_file function whenever I need to read a csv file during in my code. I added it to my code here:

```
class EmployeesList(object):

def __init__(self, list_of_employees):
    self.list_of_employees = list_of_employees

def open_and_read_file(self):
    return pd.read_csv(self.list_of_employees)

def add_employee(self, new_employee):
    list_of_employees_data = self.open_and_read_file()
    for row in list_of_employees_data:
        if new_employee.employee_id in row:
            print(EMPLOYEE_ALREADY_EXISTS_MSG)
            return
    list_of_employees_data.write("{}, {}, {}, {}\r\n").format(str(new_employee.employee_id), new_employee.name,
                                                              str(new_employee.phone), str(new_employee.age))
```

and it shows me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Can you please explain me how can I append the new data to the csv?
Thanks!

Comment: As @Pdeuxa stated, if you want to keep the updates, you have to have use `self.list_of_employees_data`. Otherwise it looks like you are trying to append to the pandas data frame. You can use the `df.append()` function to do that https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html. Please confirm if you want to also write the dataframe back to the csv file, or if you just want to keep it in the dataframe.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the quick reply :) so I do want to add the new data to the csv, in creating open_and_read_file() I just want to save the coding of this function multiple times and call it whenever I need it instead, but I want to add data/delete data from the csv given.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because there is no write function in a dataframe.

Check this link [append to a pandas dataframe](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-append/)

Also, according to your code, the attribute list_of_employees wont be modified, because there is no "self" before.
Else you add the self or you save the dataframe some where with `to_csv()`

Comment: There are some good points in there, but this is hardly an answer. Please use the comment section to state such remarks.

Answer (score 0):

> I will assume the CSV has the following header names:
>
> ```
> id, name, phone, age
> ```

There are several ways to append to the Pandas Dataframe. You can either use the `.append()` method.

```
df.append({"id:" new_employee.employee_id, "name": new_employee.name, "phone": new_employee.phone, "age": new_employee.age})
```

Alternatively you can use the `loc` property to append the data:

```
df.loc[len(df)] = [new_employee.employee_id, new_employee.name, new_employee.phone, new_employee.age]
```

Notice that I am not converting the data to strings since I assume they will be represented in the csv and in the `new_employee` object in their natural type:

```
id, name, phone, age
1, "James", "555-666-777-888", 34
2, "David", "444-555-222-111", 33
3, "Julia", "222-333-333-333", 32

-> type(id) -> int
-> type(name) -> str
-> type(phone) -> int or str, whiche ever
-> type(age) -> int
```

In case you really want to have them as strings, just add the `str()` function.

If you want to update the csv file, remember to do this in the end:

```
df.to_csv((self.list_of_employees)
```